# ggplot graphs not visible in R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

```
server <- function(input, output) {


      output$plot1<-renderPlot({

        if(input$univariate=="Age")
        {

          hist(bankchurn$Age,xlab='Age',ylab='No of Customers',col= '#45b3e0' ,main="Age")


          output$text1<-renderText("hi")`enter code here`

        }

     if(input$univariate=="Gender")
        {
          ggplot(data = bankchurn) +
            aes(x = Gender, fill = Gender) +
            geom_bar() +
            scale_fill_viridis_d(option  = "plasma") +
            theme_minimal()
          output$text1<-renderText("Gender")


        }
```

> In the above code, my first "if" statement is rendering the plot but my second if statement which is using ggplot graph is not rendering anything in the dashboard. Any idea how I can diplay ggplot graphs in situations like these.

Note: I already tried storing the graph in a variable but it is still not getting displayed in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you provide a reprex - reproducible example with an UI element made so we can further assess what needs to be changed

Comment: Also by looking at your code you have used another if statement to produce the next plot rather it should be this instead ` if( some condition){make this plot} else {plot this instead}`